# Setting a HSET data where values and fields can have values separated by whitespace in lua

Tags: redis, lua

error while calling redis.call("HSET", "key field1 'val1 val2'")

Error : ERR Wrong number of args calling Redis command from script

Saw some solutions where using +x was suggest if it was a telnet session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass a whole parameter, separate them:

```
redis.call("HSET", "key", "field1", "val1 val2")
```

Comment: the solution works but in my case I need to add multiple field and values in single HSET command, So I need to append to a string and then update, please suggest a solution for this.